# Dockerfile ENV not replacing in sed

Tags: docker, sed, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have set up dockerfile with making changes to config files with sed.
The image is a simple rtmp restreamer.

The lines in dockerfile go like:

```
RUN sed -i 's/ytkey/${YOUTUBE_KEY}/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&\
sed -i 's/fbkey/${FACEBOOK_KEY}/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

i set up ENV at the beginning

```
ENV YOUTUBE_KEY=default FACEBOOK_KEY=default
```

but after building the image it doesn't replace *ytkey* or *fbkey* as *default* but inputs a string *${YOUTUBE_KEY}*.

I have tried running

```
RUN sed -i 's/ytkey/\${YOUTUBE_KEY}/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&\
sed -i 's/fbkey/\${FACEBOOK_KEY}/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

But had the same result. Is it a problem with sed (having the env in '') or something else? Is there an alternative to sed that works with dockerfile?
Or maybe i'm doing things completely the wrong way?

Comment: The single quotes are probably causing that, yes; try double quotes instead.  You should be able to demonstrate the same thing in a non-Docker shell on your local system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double quotation marks around environment variables like this:

```
RUN sed -i 's/user/'"${YOUTUBE_KEY}"'/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&\
    sed -i 's/pid/'"${FACEBOOK_KEY}"'/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise the question is specifically about sed, but you might also consider using `envsubst` to do this, especially if you start to use more variables.

It processes stdin to stdout, so in your example you would need to use a temp file strategy, but personally I prefer that approach:

```
envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.tmp
mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.tmp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

For more complex configs, your templates would often be in a different directory anyway, so this wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but this worked for me in 2023

in the Dockerfile enter the following line where `WITH_ME` is an arg in the Dockerfile
e.g.

```
ARG WITH_ME=123

RUN sed -i -e "s|REPLACE_ME|${WITH_ME}|g" ./path/file.txt
```

the pipes that are used in the `sed` command are the key here.